# Add the virtual column with table while select * from

Tags: oracle

Want to  add column to Table A

```
Table_A 

ID,
ZONE
```

I want to add `ACCNT HAVING VALUE NEW`

Just in SELECT statement:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM TABLE_A A , (SELECT "NEW" AS ACCNT FROM DUAL) B
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont need a select statement to add a column with constant name, just write query as below:

```
SELECT *, 'New' as Zone
FROM TABLE_A
```

If you need to rename a particular column, then you could do it as follows:

```
SELECT id, accnt as New
FROM TABLE_A
```

Comment: seems that the OP need  ACCNT as column alias

Comment: Thanks @scaisEdge I have added that as well, while have advised OP to update the question as well.

Comment: ORA-00923: from keyword not found where expected , I have used in sql developer

Comment: Which query gave you that error Aman? They should both work, but which one you use depends on your requirements as SMA mentioned.

Comment: *You don't need a select statement, just write query as below* and below is a SELECT statement? I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Using below Query i am able to do the above task .

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM TABLE_A A , (SELECT "NEW" AS ACCNT FROM DUAL) B
```

Comment: The subquery is not needed. Besides, this (exactly as written) is syntactically incorrect, since strings in double-quotes are column names, and DUAL does not have a column NEW. So using this query I doubt very much that you are able to do the task. Perhaps you used 'NEW' (single quotes, not double quotes)?

Answer (score 0):

Very old thread, but giving answer to close it.

You can directly use it in your query as following:

```
SELECT A.*, 'NEW' as acct FROM TABLE_A A
```

Cheers!!